# Socket networking works only on localhost

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, connectexception

I have created two separate programs, a client and a server. I tried testing them both within eclipse and running as runnable jars on the same (Windows) machine (localhost). It worked exactly as it should.

However, when I sent clinet (and later server) to a friend of mine to test it out, it didn't work. We made sure that ports were open (even on clients side), but to no avail. It didn't work. I would just get a timeout ConnectException.

The sockets I used were 50178-50180.

I have no idea what to think of it. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

This is the socket code:

```
(serverside)
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50178);

while (true)
{
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    streamOut = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(streamOut);
    streamIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(streamIn);

    (stuff)
}

(clientside)
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 50178);

OutputStream streamOut = socket.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(streamOut);
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

I didn't include rest of the code since it I/O stuff (which does indeed work because it works over localhost).

EDIT:
I added requested code. I also tried it over two computer that were on the same network (witch local ip 192.168.1.*). It worked.

Comment: Did the person who ran the server have a public IP address? Did the client use that address?

Comment: Yes, a public IP was used. It was the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

You may already be doing this, but I believe that a call to `serverSocket.accept()` must be done. This will tell the server that it needs to wait for a connection.
If you are doing that, my best answer to you would be to perform network troubleshooting. The computers must be able to see each other on the local area network in order to be able to use just the ip address. Make sure that there is not a firewall or something like that that is preventing the connection.
If you could add the code of where the client tries to connect and where the server accepts the connection, that may be helpful.

Comment: Not calling accept() doesn't cause a connect timeout.